How to exclude some of the default attributes from timers attributes using micrometer in non springboot applications?
I want to exclude some of the default attributes from timers using micrometer in non springboot applications and prevent them from exporting to jmx servers / prometheus server.
Attached is the screenshot
I am trying to exclude the percentiles and minuterates from exporting to prometheus

sample code :-
    meterRegistry = new JmxMeterRegistry(JmxConfig.DEFAULT, Clock.SYSTEM);
    //meterRegistry.gauge("",emptyList());
    
    meterRegistry.config().meterFilter(new MeterFilter() {
        @Override
        public MeterFilterReply accept(Meter.Id id) {

            System.out.println("initialize names " + id.getName());
            System.out.println("initialize tags " + id.getTags());

            if (id.getName().endsWith("Percentile")) {
                return MeterFilterReply.DENY;
            }
            if (id.getName().endsWith("histogram")) {
                return MeterFilterReply.DENY;
            }
            if (id.getName().endsWith("MinuteRate")) {
                return MeterFilterReply.DENY;
            }
            return MeterFilterReply.NEUTRAL;
        }

    });
    //meterRegistry.config().meterFilter(MeterFilter.deny());
    Metrics.addRegistry(meterRegistry);


Look into JmxMeterRegistry, you will see that it is a DropwizardMeterRegistry and that Micrometer does not create those percentiles and rates but Dropwizard does. in one of the ctors of JmxMeterRegistry you can inject a Dropwizard JmxReporter that let's you set these properties.
So to recap, create a JmxReporter with the desired settings and inject that into Micrometer's JmxMeterRegistry.
